# Trying to animate bird for Flappy Bird program

Tags: java, javafx

I am making Flappy Bird and I am struggling to get the bird to animate. I have tried the following:

This is the class where I create the ImageView of the bird:

```
public class Bird {

    public static Image[] birdFrames = new Image[3];
    public static ImageView birdView = new ImageView();
    private static int frameCounter = 0;


    public static ImageView bird() {

        birdFrames[0] = new Image("/Resources/BirdFrame0.png");
        birdFrames[1] = new Image("/Resources/BirdFrame1.png");
        birdFrames[2] = new Image("/Resources/BirdFrame2.png");

        birdView.setImage(birdFrames[0]);

        return birdView;
    }

    public static void birdAnimate() {

        birdView.setImage(birdFrames[frameCounter++]);
        if (frameCounter == 3) {
            frameCounter = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the code I used to add it to the stage:

```
 Bird.bird().relocate(100,200);
 Bird.birdAnimate();
 root.getChildren().add(Bird.bird());
```

All I get is a non updating still image of the bird on my screen

If anyone knows why this isn't working and how to fix it, I would really appreciate the help

Comment: What UI/Graphics/animation framework are you using?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry for not mentioning, JavaFX

Comment: You're going to need some kind of loop somewhere.  Currently, you're only setting the image once.

Comment: As david wallace said, you need to put the animate function in your display loop, a loop that generates each frame of your scene.

Comment: @PatrickMurphy Could you show how exactly I would go about doing that? Where would I add that loop?

Comment: I know this could be a big change but use Processing, it is a Graphics API on top of Java that is perfect for simple games etc.

Comment: https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/133401

Comment: @PatrickMurphy Maybe I will have a look at it but how would I do this  in JavaFX?

Comment: Processing does all of this for you and will use javaFx or OpenGL 2d or 3d for output, however you can read the following article, pay attention to the game loop and the frame based animation sections. https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835

Comment: This is a youtube tutorial about how to make flappy birds in processing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXgA1d_E-jY  all you would need to do is load your images in setup(), and then use the `frameCount` variable to display the correct image of your bird.